API test // GET name value through email
So I'm trying to simulate a sort of API and
interface IUser {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
  password?: string;
}

let users: IUser[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'John', email: 'john@mail.uk' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Ivan', email: 'ivan@mail.ru' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Henry', email: 'henry@gmail.com' }
];

I'm trying through POSTMAN to GET the following:
On my "localhost/3000/users" As I add the "/search?email=john@mail.uk" on my query string, i would like to return the name of the email user.
app.get('/users/search', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.query.email as string;  // Extract and assert the type of the email query parameter
    if (!email) {  // Check if the email parameter is provided
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Email not found' });
    }
  
    const user = users.find(user => user.email === email);  // Search for the user by email
    if (user) {  // If user is found
      res.send(user.name);
    } else {  // If user is not found
      res.status(404).send({ message: 'Test' });
    }
  });

The logic seems appropriate, however when i do the GET function it returns me this
404 error and
{
    "error": "User not found"
}

I haven't set this in my conditional statements, so i guess this must be a default return string.
Hope you can help me out with this
app.get('/users/search', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.query.email as string;  // Extract and assert the type of the email query parameter
    if (!email) {  // Check if the email parameter is provided
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Email not found' });
    }
  
    const user = users.find(user => user.email === email);  // Search for the user by email
    if (user) {  // If user is found
      res.send(user.name);
    } else {  // If user is not found
      res.status(404).send({ message: 'Test' });
    }
  });

